# WP7 - listbox Binding

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an ObservableCollection that I want to bind to my listbox...

```
lbRosterList.ItemsSource = App.ViewModel.rosterItemsCollection;
```

However, in that collection I have another collection within it:

```
 [DataMember]
    public ObservableCollection<PersonDetail> ContactInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return _ContactInfo;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _ContactInfo)
            {
                _ContactInfo = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ContactInfo");
            }
        }
    }
```

PersonDetail contains 2 properties: ***name and e-mail***

I would like the listbox to have those values for each item in rosterItemsCollection

```
RosterId = 0;
RosterName = "test";
ContactInfo.name = "Art";
ContactInfo.email = "art@something.com";

RosterId = 0;
RosterName = "test"
ContactInfo.name = "bob";
ContactInfo.email = "bob@something.com";

RosterId = 1;
RosterName = "test1"
ContactInfo.name = "chris";
ContactInfo.email = "chris@something.com";

RosterId = 1;
RosterName = "test1"
ContactInfo.name = "Sam";
ContactInfo.email = "sam@something.com";
```

I would like that listboxes to display the ContactInfo information.

I hope this makes sense...

My XAML that I've tried with little success:

```
<listbox x:Name="lbRosterList" ItemsSource="rosterItemCollection">
<textblock x:name="itemText" text="{Binding Path=name}"/>
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your Binding Path to this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbRosterList" DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding rosterItemCollection}">
<TextBlock x:Name="itemText" Text="{Binding Path=ContactInfo.name}"/>
```

Then in your code do this (after InitializeComponents in the page constructor):

```
lbRosterList.DataContext = App.ViewModel;
```

Excellent reference for this kind of thing in this [free book](http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/index.html) by Charles Petzold: Chapter 12, pg 363.

You can also remove the `DataContext` attribute from the listbox and set the `DataContext` of the page itself.  If you create a new databound application, you will see what I mean with their default example.

Comment: I downloaded that book and looked specifically over that page.  I tried your suggestion and although it looks like some binding is happening the text of the "name" property is not displaying...

Comment: Did this work for you, or were you able to get something else to work?

Comment: Actually I changed course...   I did skim that book and it is a great resource.  Thanks!