# WP7 Databinding to Listbox from code with DataTemplate

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone-7, dynamic, listbox

Here is the XAML i use to display the Listbox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="groupedList" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
          <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Name="myTemplate">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" FontWeight="Bold" x:Name="templateHeader" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" x:Name="templateCaption"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

The problem is that the Databinding has to be created in code since there is different data each time. (In fact the data comes by using an indexer[] with a dynamically selected field in a sql). My question now is how to apply the Databinding to the Listbox and the DataTemplate from code. As far as i can see there is no way access the items defined inside of a DataTemplate.... Can anyone help ?

This is my attempt so far:

```
Binding binding = new Binding("["+CaptionField+"]");
        binding.Source = this.controller.table.Rows;
        binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(this.groupedList.Items, ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
        this.groupedList.SetBinding(null, binding);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was about to give you a simple example but I think there are plenty of better example, so please take a look at these site to see if it help:
[WP7 - listbox Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576980/wp7-listbox-binding)

[listbox-data-binding](http://3water.wordpress.com/2010/07/25/listbox-on-wp7/)

Please comment if anything wasn't clear.

Comment: I'm sorry but i think u didn't read my question at all. I do not know the bindings at compile time... I have to generate the bindings at runtime and i also have to use datatemplates on the listbox

Comment: I'm sorry. I wasn't clear what you're trying to do, try if this help: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/WP7-ListBox-SelectedItem