# Are there some samples about moving and removing of a row of listbox

Tags: windows-phone-7

I try to migrate my iphone app to wp7.
On ios, UITableview is well designed, and very easy to code.
I have the some book about wp7, but there are no detail concerned about moving and removing of a row of listbox.

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to think that Windows Phone is also well designed. :)

To simply remove an item from a `ListBox` in your codebehind, you need to get a reference to the `ListItem` that you want to remove. For example, to remove the currently selected item:

```
var myListItem = myListBox.SelectedItem;
```

Then you can remove it with:

```
myListBox.Items.Remove(myListItem);
```

In order to address your question about moving items, we'd need to know more about how you're populating the `ListBox`. Are you using databinding, or adding items with `myListBox.Items.Add(myListItem)`?

If I needed to move items between two lists, I would create a public `List<MyItem>` property for each list and databind each list to its own `ListBox`. Then I might do something like this (working from memory here):

```
var itemToMove = myList1.Remove(myListBox1.SelectedItem);
myList2.Add(itemToMove);
myListBox1.DataBind();
myListBox2.DataBind();
```

There's a much better way to do this, using `INotifiyPropertyChanged`, but I suspect you need to play around with the basics for a while to get comfortable in C#.

Bonus tip: Windows Phone is very similar to Silverlight, and you can usually find more information if you search for Silverlight examples.

Comment: If you're not using databinding. And this doesn't solve how to answer moving a listbox item, which is more complicated.

Comment: Fair enough, but the original question didn't mention databinding.

Comment: I do not think listbox is well designed for the small screen size of a phone on mobile market. This is one of the reasons Microsoft lags to Apple. On iosUITableView, you can do editing on each row itself. rather than use a button outside wp7 listbox to edit the items of the listbox

Answer (score 0):

In WP7, usually we set the ItemSource of listbox, when our source changes its changes automatically propagate to the UI due to data binding ( it is known as one way binding ; source to UI ).

so what ever you do ( add, update or delete) in itemsource, it reflects to UI.

[databinding in wp7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576980/wp7-listbox-binding)